# Nemo doesn't show up on search

Tags: fedora, gnome, nemo

When you press the WIN-key or press "Activities" you can start typing and you will find installed programs.

Currently, when I search for Nemo it doesn't show up. I'm on stock Fedora 23 with default desktop environment and I have two other computers with the same system but searching Nemo works there..

When I start Nemo on command line it doesn't show up in the left application panel neither.

How can this be and how do I repair this?

Comment: what is Nemo? How did you install it? Does it have `*.desktop` file?

Comment: Nemo is a file manager. In fedora you install it with `dnf install nemo`. And yes, there is a desktop file.

Comment: AFAIK, it is because of the [missing `appdata.xml`](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:AppData), but there might be more problems. Anyway, this file manager is for Cinnamon and not for Gnome (you can use Nautilus here).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would like to mention that, as far as I know, Nemo comes with another desktop different than Gnome, that is, Cinnamon so it's kind of "configured" for that one.

Following up the suggestion made earlier about the .desktop file, I did the following:

1. I got the location of the .desktop file for Nemo:

   ```
   # rpm -ql nemo | grep desktop
   /usr/bin/nemo-desktop
   /usr/share/applications/nemo-autorun-software.desktop
   /usr/share/applications/nemo-autostart.desktop
   /usr/share/applications/nemo.desktop     <<< this is the one we need
   /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/actions/nemo-desktop-scale-symbolic.svg
   ```
2. After reviewing it, I found the following parameter which seemed suspicious to me for the behavior I was experiencing:

   ```
   # grep -i only /usr/share/applications/nemo.desktop
   OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
   ```
3. I commented this line out and now Nemo appeared in the search when pressing the Super-key.

   ```
   # vim /usr/share/applications/nemo.desktop
   # grep -i only /usr/share/applications/nemo.desktop
   #OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
   ```